Matrices $A$ and $B$ are given. How to find matrix $C$ and $D$, so that $CAD = B$?
Given $$A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$
and $$B =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
How to find $C$ and $D$, so that $C A D = B$?
I have basic knowledge in linear algebra (e.g. transformation matrix, singular value decomposition), but have no idea how to solve the above problem.

Hint: check the ranks of $A$ and $B$.

@RobertIsrael The rank of A is 2, and the rank of B is 4

@kandb It does not work because the non-linear equation system cannot be solved

Do you know anything about how the rank of a matrix product compares to the ranks of the individual matrices? That is key to this question

@whpowell96 Could you please explain more? It seems that I do not know anything about that.

Such $C$ and $D$ do not exist.
Proof: Obviously $C$ should be a $4\times2$ matrix while $D$ a $3\times6$ matrix. We see that $E=CA$ is a $4\times3$ matrix and $D$ has rank at most $3$ (because D has only $3$ rows). Therefore $ED$ has rank at most $3$ (because each row of $ED$ is a linear combination of rows of $D$). However, $B$ has rank $4$ so cannot be equal to $ED$.

True, but in fact $A$ has rank $2$, so $CAD$ has rank at most $2$.
